# how to see data that I input on android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I just created a `login` and `register` on my application.

I want to see the `data` that i just `input` on the `register`. Where can I see that `data` ? Can I just see it like sql using `navicat` or `sqlyog`?

If I want to create another function like a `crud`, should I put the `queries` inside the `sqlitehelper` class too ?

please tell me if I'm wrong, and where is my .db file ?

Answer (score 0):

> If I want to create another function like a crud, should I put the
>   queries inside the sqlitehelper class too ?

Yes, You can do.

> Can I just see it like sql using navicat or sqlyog?

You can't just see the data directly as there is no inbuilt tool.

> I want to see the data that i just input on the register. Where can I
>   see that data ?

For testing, one of the easier ways could be to include a method, in the SQLiteHelper class, along the lines of :-

```
public void DisplayTableData(String table) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor csr = db.query(table, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr); //<<<<<<<<<< will dump the Cursor to the Log
    csr.close();
}
```

- As per the comments this dumps the cursor to the log using a utility provided with the Android SDK. The cursor is create using the **SQliteDatabase**'s **query** method and will extract all columns from the table as per the paremeter passed to the method.

An example of using the above from an activity is :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper mDBHlpr;
    Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;

        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this); //<<<<<<<<<< instantiate the SQLiteHelper
        mDBHlpr.logTable(DBHelper.TBL_RETAILER); //<<<<<<<<<< invoke the logTable method

    }
}
```

The result, nothing that, the table **retailer** (as per `public static final String TBL_RETAILER = "retailer";`) exists and has some data added, would be along the lines of :-

```
2019-02-24 16:23:00.925 31737-31737/mjt.pvcheck I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@57a9fc5
2019-02-24 16:23:00.925 31737-31737/mjt.pvcheck I/System.out: 0 {
2019-02-24 16:23:00.926 31737-31737/mjt.pvcheck I/System.out:    _id=1
2019-02-24 16:23:00.926 31737-31737/mjt.pvcheck I/System.out:    retailerName=Retailer1
2019-02-24 16:23:00.926 31737-31737/mjt.pvcheck I/System.out: }
2019-02-24 16:23:00.926 31737-31737/mjt.pvcheck I/System.out: 1 {
2019-02-24 16:23:00.926 31737-31737/mjt.pvcheck I/System.out:    _id=2
2019-02-24 16:23:00.926 31737-31737/mjt.pvcheck I/System.out:    retailerName=Retailer2
2019-02-24 16:23:00.926 31737-31737/mjt.pvcheck I/System.out: }
2019-02-24 16:23:00.927 31737-31737/mjt.pvcheck I/System.out: <<<<<
```

- This shows that there are 2 rows in the table that has been defined as having 2 columns namely

  - **_id** (first row's value is **1**, second row's value is **2**) and
  - **retailerName** (first rows's value is **Retailer1**, the second row's value is **Reatiler2**)
- The results are specific to the App that this was used within, you would expect different results.

Of course this is just a very rudimentary check/display of the data.

> where is my .db file ?

If you haven't provided a specific location for the database then it will be in **/data/data/the_package_name/databases/**

- where the_package_name would be as per the package that the SQLiteHelper class is part of.

e.g. in the above the package is mjt.pvcheck, using device explorer would be something like :-

[image]

- The first highlight is the package (mjt.pvcheck) folder within /data/data
- The second highlight is the databases folder
- **pvcheck** is the actual database file in the above App (there is no requirement for a specific file extension BUT the file name and the database name MUST match).
- The existenece of the files with **-shm** and **-wal** appendage that are otherwise the same as the database file name are because the SQLite database is using Write Ahead Logging (WAL). If not there may be a -journal file if the older journal mode is used. (From Android Pie the default has been changed to WAL).